# g++ lambda declared using local type ... is used but never defined - really an error?

Tags: c++, lambda, g++

g++ won't compile this code without `-fpermssive`.  Neither clang nor icc complains.  Is this code legal?

My intention is to declare `wrapped_foo` in one compilation unit and to define it in a separate compilation unit. Is that possible?

bug1.cpp

```
auto wrap(int (*f)(int)){
    return [f](int i) {
        return f(i);
    };
}

int foo(int);
extern decltype(wrap(foo)) wrapped_foo;

int func(){
    return wrapped_foo(2);
}
```

```
garden with -m gcc/7.3.0-01c7/bin g++ -Wall -Wextra  bug1.cpp -c
bug1.cpp:8:28: error: ‘wrap(int (*)(int))::<lambda(int)> wrapped_foo’, declared using local type ‘wrap(int (*)(int))::<lambda(int)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
 extern decltype(wrap(foo)) wrapped_foo;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Jarod42's code works on the Big Three platforms if the "extern" is ditched. Makes me go hmmm. Still, I think `std::function` is worth a look. It wraps lambdas, no muss, no fuss.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible:

header file

```
inline auto wrap(int (*f)(int))
{
    return [f](int i) {
        return f(i);
    };
}

int foo(int i);
extern decltype(wrap(&foo)) wrapped_foo;
```

cpp file

```
int foo(int i) { return i;}
decltype(wrap(foo)) wrapped_foo = wrap(&foo);
```

usage

```
int func(){
    return wrapped_foo(42);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/EwGkoN)

Comment: I that standard-compliant? VC++17 will not compile it.

Comment: Don't know why visual refuse the `extern`, but without it compiles [Demo](http://rextester.com/MZNU81703). gcc/clang accept it as-is.

Comment: It's a mystery to me.

Comment: @Jarod42 I couldn't make it compile with real separate files. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c865bdbc21f8bc2e)

Comment: I can't make it work in separate files either (with gcc).  Specifically, I can't compile 'usage'.  I #include-ed the header file at the top of the usage file and got the same "declared using local type" ... "is used but not defined" error as before.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to define `wrapped_foo` in any other compilation unit because every lambda type is unique. So even though this code technically is valid it will never succeed to link. G++ just goes a bit further and refuses to compile this as well.

Also here is a simpler code to reproduce the issue:

```
auto l = [](){};
extern decltype(l) wrapped_foo;

void func(){
    wrapped_foo();
}
```

Comment: The OP's code is not  technically valid even in one compilation unit, and even if the "extern" is removed.  It is not possible to construct an instance of a lambda.

Comment: Show me how to construct an instance of a lambda.

Comment: What compiler will allow the OP's code if it is all in one compilation unit, and the "extern" keyword is removed?

Comment: @JiveDadson: You cannot default construct a lamba type, but you can still copy construct it.